# Unable to do unmanaged deployment on JBoss 6.1 EAP through management console

Tags: java, jboss, war

I am trying unmanaged deployment of WAR file on JBoss 6.1 EAP through management console user interface.
I follow following steps:

1. I go to manage deployments.
2. Click on Add button.
3. Select unmanaged tab.
4. I give the path of the exploded WAR context, keep relative to text box empty since its optional, name and runtime name.
5. I click on next button.
   After clicking nothing happens. There is no error message nor exception trace.

Please let me know I have missed any step or is it an issue in JBoss 6.1 EAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for the issue. While giving path of the exploded WAR in Windows environment, instead "***E:\test.war***" the path should be given as "***E:\test.war***".
Now my WAR is getting deployed.
The help for unmanaged deployment is not present in Red Hat Documentation. Figured it out myself.